# firebase callable node function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I try to use a node function in firebase callable function and wehn I try to use it as described I see this warning on VS code. **any help? on what I can do**
*module "c:/Users/firat/Desktop/vuedg3/functions/node_modules/iyzipay/lib/Iyzipay"
Could not find a declaration file for module 'iyzipay'. 'c:/Users/firat/Desktop/vuedg3/functions/node_modules/iyzipay/lib/Iyzipay.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/iyzipay` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'iyzipay';`ts(7016)*

and this callable function return **null** when I try and call it from web app
this is my entire code

```
exports.trypay = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

var Iyzipay = require('iyzipay');

var iyzipay = new Iyzipay({
    apiKey: "sandbox-11",
    secretKey: "sandbox-11",
    uri: 'https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com'
});

var request = {
    locale: Iyzipay.LOCALE.TR,
    conversationId: '123456789',
    price: '1',
    paidPrice: '1.2',
    currency: Iyzipay.CURRENCY.TRY,
    installment: '1',
    basketId: 'B67832',
    paymentChannel: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_CHANNEL.WEB,
    paymentGroup: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_GROUP.LISTING,
    paymentCard: {
        cardHolderName: 'John Doe',
        cardNumber: '5528790000000008',
        expireMonth: '12',
        expireYear: '2030',
        cvc: '123',
        registerCard: '0'
    },
    buyer: {
        id: 'BY789',
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Doe',
        gsmNumber: '+905350000000',
        email: 'email@email.com',
        identityNumber: '74300864791',
        lastLoginDate: '2015-10-05 12:43:35',
        registrationDate: '2013-04-21 15:12:09',
        registrationAddress: 'Nidakule Göztepe, Merdivenköy Mah. Bora Sok. No:1',
        ip: '85.34.78.112',
        city: 'Istanbul',
        country: 'Turkey',
        zipCode: '34732'
    },
    shippingAddress: {
        contactName: 'Jane Doe',
        city: 'Istanbul',
        country: 'Turkey',
        address: 'Nidakule Göztepe, Merdivenköy Mah. Bora Sok. No:1',
        zipCode: '34742'
    },
    billingAddress: {
        contactName: 'Jane Doe',
        city: 'Istanbul',
        country: 'Turkey',
        address: 'Nidakule Göztepe, Merdivenköy Mah. Bora Sok. No:1',
        zipCode: '34742'
    },
    basketItems: [
        {
            id: 'BI101',
            name: 'Binocular',
            category1: 'Collectibles',
            category2: 'Accessories',
            itemType: Iyzipay.BASKET_ITEM_TYPE.PHYSICAL,
            price: '0.3'
        },
        {
            id: 'BI102',
            name: 'Game code',
            category1: 'Game',
            category2: 'Online Game Items',
            itemType: Iyzipay.BASKET_ITEM_TYPE.VIRTUAL,
            price: '0.5'
        },
        {
            id: 'BI103',
            name: 'Usb',
            category1: 'Electronics',
            category2: 'Usb / Cable',
            itemType: Iyzipay.BASKET_ITEM_TYPE.PHYSICAL,
            price: '0.2'
        }
    ]
};
iyzipay.payment.create(request, function (err, result) {
    return('result:'+result + 'error:'+err);
});
})
```

Comment: Did you install the iyzipay package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/iyzipay

Comment: can someone help with this declaration module? please

Comment: yes i did install it

Comment: do you see it in your `package.json` file?

Comment: yes. they're in dependencies in my package.json file. i installed it in both functions and my nuxt app to make sure.

Comment: I've rapidly looked at the Iyzipay package and it seems that calls to the create() method does not return promises. You will need to ["promisify" the callback function](https://javascript.info/promisify). Why that? I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: thank you very much!. i wil look into that

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.